# creating an Environment object

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

can someone please help me with this. Whenever I am trying to declare gp as an Environment object, the list disappears. The list works fine when the gp is a @State variable. Could you please help me with creating gp as a global variable so that it works in another screen of Final. I want to call gp in the Final screen so that I can use the value of gp to calculate something else.

```
import SwiftUI
    
    
    struct Calculation: View {
        
        @State var load1 = Float()
        @State var load2 = Float()
        //@State var gp : Float = 0
        @State var rate: Float = 0
        @ObservedObject var taskStore = TaskStore()
        @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
        func addNewToDo() {
            taskStore.tasks.append(Task(id: String(taskStore.tasks.count + 1), toDoItem: " Earning: =  \(rate.description)", amount: rate))
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    List {
                        
                        Section(header:Text("load 2"))
                        {
                            TextField("Enter value of load 1", value: $load1, format: .number)
                            TextField("Enter value of load 1", value: $load2, format: .number)
                        }
                        
                        HStack {
                            Button(String(format: "Add Load"), action: {
                                print("pay for the shift is ")
                                print(Rocky(mypay: rate))
                                userSettings.gp += rate
                            })
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                addNewToDo()
                                Rocky(mypay: rate)
                            },
                            label: {
                                Text(" ")
                            })
                        }
                        
                        ForEach(self.taskStore.tasks) { task in
                            Text(task.toDoItem)
                        }
                        .onMove(perform : self.move)
                        .onDelete(perform : self.delete) //For each
                        
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("SHIFTS")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton()) //List
                    
                    Text("Gross Pay = $\(userSettings.gp) ")
                     NavigationLink(destination: Final(), label: {Text("Next")})
                }.onAppear()
                
            }
        }
        
        func Rocky(mypay: Float)
        {
            rate = load1 + load2
            print("Sus \(userSettings.gp)")
        }
        func move(from source : IndexSet, to destination : Int)
        {
            taskStore.tasks.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
        }
        func delete(at offsets : IndexSet) {
            if let index = offsets.first {  //<-- Here
                let task = taskStore.tasks[index]
                userSettings.gp -= task.amount
            }
            taskStore.tasks.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
    
    struct Final: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
        var body: some View {
            Text("Final result \(userSettings.gp)")
        }
    }
```

Another part of the file is as below:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
class UserSettings: ObservableObject
{
@Published var gp : Float = 0
    
}

struct Task : Identifiable {
    var id = String()
    var toDoItem = String()
    var amount : Float = 0 //<-- Here
}

class TaskStore : ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [Task]()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use your `UserSettings` ObservableObject, you need to declare it before you call the `Calculation` view.
Pass it to  `Calculation` using `.environmentObject(userSettings)` so that it is available in `Calculation`
and all "sub views" (like `Final`), such as in this example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var userSettings = UserSettings()   // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Calculation().environmentObject(userSettings)  // <-- here
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: here is the full test code I used:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var userSettings = UserSettings()   // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Calculation().environmentObject(userSettings)  // <-- here
    }
}

struct Calculation: View {
    
    @State var load1 = Float()
    @State var load2 = Float()
    @State var rate: Float = 0
    @StateObject var taskStore = TaskStore()  // <-- here
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    
    func addNewToDo() {
        taskStore.tasks.append(Task(id: String(taskStore.tasks.count + 1), toDoItem: " Earning: =  \(rate.description)", amount: rate))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    Section(header:Text("load 2")){
                        TextField("Enter value of load 1", value: $load1, format: .number)
                        TextField("Enter value of load 1", value: $load2, format: .number)
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Button(String(format: "Add Load"), action: {
                            print("pay for the shift is ")
                            print(Rocky(mypay: rate))
                            userSettings.gp += rate
                        })
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            addNewToDo()
                            Rocky(mypay: rate)
                        },
                               label: {
                            Text(" ")
                        })
                    }
                    
                    ForEach(self.taskStore.tasks) { task in
                        Text(task.toDoItem)
                    }
                    .onMove(perform : self.move)
                    .onDelete(perform : self.delete) //For each
                    
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("SHIFTS")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton()) //List
                
                Text("Gross Pay = $\(userSettings.gp) ")
                NavigationLink(destination: Final(), label: {Text("Next")})
            }.onAppear()
            
        }
    }
    
    func Rocky(mypay: Float){
        rate = load1 + load2
        print("Sus \(userSettings.gp)")
    }
    
    func move(from source : IndexSet, to destination : Int){
        taskStore.tasks.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets : IndexSet) {
        if let index = offsets.first {  //<-- Here
            let task = taskStore.tasks[index]
            userSettings.gp -= task.amount
        }
        taskStore.tasks.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

struct Final: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    var body: some View {
        Text("Final result \(userSettings.gp)")
    }
}


class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var gp : Float = 0
}

struct Task : Identifiable {
    var id = String()
    var toDoItem = String()
    var amount : Float = 0 //<-- Here
}

class TaskStore : ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [Task]()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand. Can you please help me run the above program where I can view the value of gp in another view as well and the list shows up too. If you run the above program with gp as a @State var, it works fine. However, when you declare gp as an environment object, everything works fine however, the list doesn't appear when you click Add load button. Thanks

Comment: updated my answer with the full code I use to show that you can use `userSettings.gp` in `Final` view and in `Calculation` using the approach I outlined.

Comment: Note: to add a new `Task` to `taskStore` when you click the button, use `@StateObject var taskStore = TaskStore()` instead of `@ObservedObject var taskStore = TaskStore()`

Comment: But the list still doesn't appear when you click on the Add Load Button. You can check the list appears fine when you declare gp as @State var in Calculation().

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can get it worked using the StateObject instead of ObservedObject for taskStore. Thanks mate.